# Jitsi-meet compiled from source, but got error when run dev server

Tags: jitsi-meet

Follow the Github (https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet), I compiled the source code.

When run on dev server (localhost:8080), it got javascript error as below:

```
translation.js:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at new Translation (translation.js:26)
    at Module../modules/translation/translation.js (translation.js:59)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../app.js (app.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.0 (app.bundle.min.js?v=3539:274618)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Just add following code to resolve webpack build issue of $ in webpack.config.js file.

Include below-mentioned at the top of the file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
```

Include below-mentioned code into the config section:

```
plugins: [
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",  
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })
]
```

Comment: Helped me. But why isn't this checked in the repo?

Answer (score 0):

You must install dependencies with this command in the root directory of jitsi-meet:

> npm install

If not working or already did, try to delete the node_modules directory and rerun the command